# sending JSON to PHP using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm sending a fairly simple compilation of object to a php script using the jQuery's `.ajax`. I want to extract one value from each object in the PHP script. The javascript is:

```
var obj = [{id:1, name:"val1"}, {id:2, name:"val2"},{id:3, name:"val3"}];

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "call.php",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {type: "stream", q: JSON.stringify(obj)},
            success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                     }
          });
```

The call.php file is written as:

```
if($_GET['type']=='stream'){
    $obj = json_decode($_GET['q']);

    for($i=0;$obj[$i];$i++){
    echo $obj[$i]->{'name'}." ";
    }
}
```

However this returns 0, and I simply cannot figure out why.

Secondly a attempted using `type:"POST"` in the javascript, and `$_POST` in php, but that failed altogether.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing `$_GET` in your call.php script to see what jQuery and PHP have done with your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 data: {type: "stream", q: JSON.stringify(obj)},
```

instead of this use

```
 data: {type: "stream", q: obj},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax options. `contentType` option is for data being sent only.

After adding dataType, try this:

```
echo $_GET['q'];
```

It should simply return the json string you send. If not need to look at request in console for problems

Comment: hi mate, `dataType` is not related to send data, but for format of receive data you expecting.